# Django URL MAC Address Matching

Tags: python, regex, django

I am having a strange issue with pattern matching in Django where part of the regular expression is being inserted into the path.

Test Mac: `08:00:27:13:5A:B2`

MAC_ADDRESS_PATTERN:`(?P<mac_address>[\dA-F]{2}(?:[-:][\dA-F]{2}){5})`

Regex test in [Pythex](http://pythex.org/?regex=%28%3FP%3Cmac_address%3E[%5CdA-F]%7B2%7D%28%3F%3A[-%3A][%5CdA-F]%7B2%7D%29%7B5%7D%29&test_string=08%3A00%3A27%3A13%3A5A%3AB2&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Url Resolved in Swagger: `GET /hostmanager/api/host/lookup/mac/{mac_address}{5})/`

Resulting Request: `api/host/lookup/mac/08%3A00%3A27%3A13%3A5A%3AB2{5})/`

This results in a 404 Error. If I remove the `{5})` and repeat the request it is successful

From Python `manage.py show_urls`:

```
/hostmanager/api/host/lookup/mac/<mac_address>{5})/ rest_framework.decorators.hostLookupMacAddress  host_lookup_mac_address
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from HostManager.Api.views import (
    hostLookupMacAddress,
)

MAC_ADDRESS_PATTERN = r'(?P<mac_address>([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name="host_manager_api_home"),
    url(r'^host/lookup/mac/%s/'% MAC_ADDRESS_PATTERN , hostLookupMacAddress  , name='host_lookup_mac_address'),

]
```

Comment: try changing all the capturing groups other than named capturing groups to non-capturing groups. `MAC_ADDRESS_PATTERN = r'(?P<mac_address>(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))'`

Comment: don't you repeat the same pattern for 5 times?

Comment: This results in the following url from python manage.py show_urls:  GET /hostmanager/api/host/lookup/{mac_address}{5}{var})/